# Vector and tensor differential operation. How can you prove left hand side to be equal to right hand side? s is sclar and v is vector.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, tensors

$$\begin{align}
(\nabla\cdot s{\bf v}) &= (\nabla s\cdot {\bf v}) + s(\nabla \cdot {\bf v})\\
(\nabla\cdot[{\bf v}\times{\bf w}]) &= 
({\bf w}\cdot[\nabla \times {\bf v}]) -
({\bf v}\cdot[\nabla \times {\bf w}])
\end{align}$$

How can you prove gradient dots scalar vector to equal to the right hand side?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to express the gradient, the curl and the divergence in tensor notation.

The gradient of a scalar function $s(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ is straight forward
$$(\nabla s)_i=\frac{\partial s(x^1,\dots,x^n)}{\partial x^i}=\partial_is$$

The divergence of a vector field ($\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v}$) is the contracted covariant derivative

$$\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v}=\nabla_iv^i$$

For the curl and the cross product we need to make some assumptions. In a 3 dimensional differentiable manifold with a symmetric connection the covariant derivative of the permutation symbols vanish identically. The components of the curl $\nabla \times \mathbf{v}$ can be interpreted as

$$\left(\nabla \times \mathbf{v}\right)^k=\varepsilon^{ijk}\nabla_i v_j\quad\left(=\varepsilon^{ijk}\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x^i}\right)$$

Finally, the components of the cross product of two vectors, $\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{w}$, can be interpreted as

$$\left(\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{w}\right)^i=\varepsilon^{ijk}v_j w_k$$

Now we have everything we need to investigate the expressions, lets try $\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w})$. Using the product rule of the covariant derivative, remembering that the covariant derivative of the permutation symbols vanish identically (according to our assumptions), we end up with the following in tensor notation

$$\nabla_i(\varepsilon^{ijk}v_jw_k)=\varepsilon^{ijk}(\nabla_i v_j)w_k+\varepsilon^{ijk}v_j(\nabla_iw_k)$$

If we interpret the contraction $w_ka^k$ as the dot product $\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{a}$ the first term on the right hand side is obviously $\mathbf{w}\cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{v})$. For the second term we use the skew symmetric property of the permutation symbol $\varepsilon^{ijk}=-\varepsilon^{ikj}$

$$w_k\varepsilon^{ijk}\nabla_iv_j-v_j\varepsilon^{ikj}\nabla_iw_k=\mathbf{w}\cdot(\nabla\times\mathbf{v})-\mathbf{v}\cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{w})$$

The last identity $(\nabla\cdot s\mathbf{v})$ of your question is left as an exercise.